# Should included PHP scripts use PHP tags?

Tags: php

If I `include` or `require` one PHP script from another, e.g. `include 'header.php';`, should the included PHP script also use the opening `<?php` and closing `?>` tags, or not?

Whether the tags are present or not, the script loads correctly. But I'm unsure which is the correct procedure. My concerns are: (1) by using the tags again the PHP engine might start up twice and waste resources, (2) by not using the tags, this may be incorrect and could break in future, also other people might be able to see the PHP code (if it were inside of the public directory).

**EDIT**

People are misunderstanding this question. Here is some background: when you `include` or `require` a file it is dropped into place in the parent file dynamically and they are parsed as one script. The included script is not executed/interpreted separately, it just continues. This is why the tags are *NOT* needed. That is not my question. My question is whether it is better (recommended by PHP?) to use the PHP tags in this case, or to exclude them entirely from the included scripts.

Comment: OK... but why is that? What is happening?

Comment: without tags server cannot identify php script to run. so you need it..

Comment: Incorrect, it will run if it is included from a PHP file which does have tags already present. That is why I asked the question. `include` drops the file into place in the parent file before the file is processed.

Comment: There is no such thing as a PHP script. There are only files that contain PHP code blocks. If there isn't at least one `<?php` opening tag in a file, then the PHP interpreter will never fire up, and the file will simply be treated as output.

Comment: You're over thinking it. Any PHP code should be wrapped in `<?php` tags (with the exception of a closing tag, which is unnecessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your include/require file is PHP, open it with the php tag `<?php`. Generally, you don't close the php tag if there is nothing after it as it is optional.

> The **closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional**, and
>   in some cases **omitting it is helpful when using include or require, so
>   unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files**, and you will
>   still be able to add headers to the response later. It is also handy
>   if you use output buffering, and would not like to see added unwanted
>   whitespace at the end of the parts generated by the included files.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: Open it with PHP quotes anyways. This will also allow some editors and IDEs (e.g. as Notepad++) to properly interpret the file as PHP for outlining purposes like color coding texts.

Comment: Thank you, but, will this waste resources or does PHP just ignore the second tags?

Comment: if a few cpu cycles on your server is an issue - you have much bigger issues.